# BigQuery Data Location Setting

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to determine "BigQuery Data Location Setting", similar to "Cloud Storage Data Location Setting" or “Datastore Data Location Setting”?

Apparently there are some legal & tax issues for companies operating outside of the US when using services hosted in the US. Our legal guys have asked me to configure the BigQuery location to be in EU. But i couldn't find where to configure this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There isn't currently a way to locate your BigQuery data in the EU. Right now, all of it is located in the United States.

That said, one of the reasons why this hasn't been done yet is due to lack of customer interest in EU datacenters. If you have a relationship with google cloud support and want this feature, please let them know. Alternately, vote up the question and we'll take that into account when we prioritize new features.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have changed now, so you can actually select the EU datacenter:

http://techcrunch.com/2015/04/16/google-opens-cloud-dataflow-to-all-developers-launches-european-zone-for-bigquery/

Answer (score 0):

Another issue arises when you want to copy datasets from one region to the other which is not currently possibly (at least directly). Here is how you can check the location of your dataset. Open up a [Google Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quickstart) and enter this command:

`bq show --format=prettyjson {PROJECT_ID}:{DATASET_NAME} | grep location`

However, note that you cannot edit the location. You will need to backup/export all your tables, delete the dataset, and recreate the dataset with the desired location.